# how to plot surface that has x,y,z vectors?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I have a file containing some xyz data points and am trying to create a surface plot out of points in this dataset but for some reason my plot always comes out looking horribly deformed.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a grid available for the points, then it is possible to directly feed them to ILSurface. If not (scattered data) you would need to interpolate them in such way to get a grid. Or you have to wait for our upcoming interpolation toolbox, which will provide such feature!

This is currently not possible, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking into projecting 3D points on a 2D surface. The basic formula looks something like

```
projectedX = x / z
projectedY = y / z
```

and if you consider the screen space, you have something like this:

```
projectedX = x * ScreenWidth / z - ScreenWidth / 2
projectedY = y * ScreenHeight / z - ScreenHeight / 2
```

This should get you started on the projection.